# C# Xamarin.iOS property access returns null while it is not in object

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, realm

I am facing a weird and disturbing problem in Xamarin app.
My piece of code below is in a project library which is shared with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS apps.

On the Android app, everything goes well and the code produces the exact expected behaviour.

But for strange reasons, it differs on the iOS app.
The value of `dbData.Status` is always `null`.

The odd thing is when I do a "QuickWatch" on the `dbData` object, the value of the `Status` property is not null and well set.

```cs
namespace MyApp.Services
{

    public class MyPersistedObject : RealmObject
    {
        public static MyPersistedObject GetDbData()
        {
            var dbData = Ctx.Db.All<MyPersistedObject>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (dbData == null)
            {
                dbData = new MyPersistedObject();
                Ctx.Db.Write(() => Ctx.Db.Add(dbData));
            }

            return dbData;
        }

        public static void SetLocationEnabled(bool isEnabled = true)
        {
            var dbData = GetDbData();

            if (isEnabled && dbData.Status == "disabled_status")
            {
                Ctx.Db.Write(() => dbData.Status = "enabled_status");
            }
            else if (!isEnabled && dbData.Status == "enabled_status")
            {
                Ctx.Db.Write(() => dbData.Status = "disabled_status");
            }

            Ctx.Db.Write(() => dbData.Enabled = isEnabled);
        }

        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the entire solution and running it in Debug it's difficult to say exactly what the problem is (for example what class is the Ctx.Db object?), however my guess is that you have an initialization issue in your data store (Ctx.Db object) for iOS.

The most likely scenario you are seeing is that when you call GetDbData() it is returning an instantiated object but the Status property is null on iOS (which is the default for a string). Then neither of the if statements in SetLocationEnabled() are true, as the status property is not set, and remains null.

There are two possibilities to cause this, either a new MyPersistedObject() is not instantiated correctly for iOS, which could only really happen if its different for the two platforms and is injected, which seems very unlikely as its probably just common code; or there is a problem with how you have initialized the entry in your data store for iOS.

Set some breakpoints when you initialize your data store with the default values on both platforms and you should be able to tack down where there issue is being caused and how to correct it.